# Is it appropriate to apply to full-time job openings if you're interested in part-time work (or less)?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, applications, part-time, fulltime

I managed to find jobs that I would love to do in addition to my part-time job, either for 10 or 20 hours a week. However, those job postings are for full-time roles. **Can I still apply for that job and indicate to the employer (either in my cover letter or on the interview itself) that I would be interested in only working part-time and explain to them my situation?**

I should note that my formal experience level for the jobs I'm considering is junior, but I did have non-formal experience and education that would set me apart from others in a positive light.

Comment: What general field is this ?

Comment: @Fattie Technology.

Comment: If this is software, I'd say (1) it's pretty common to state "I'm available half-time".  (Forget "10", nobody will do that.)  Since (2) there is a big demand at the moment for programmers, it can happen.  However (3) do note that many (not all) team leads simply believe that it's impossible to program half-time so they'd just (harmlessly) dismiss your application.  So in short yes in software it's *perfectly normal, not impolite* to send in a cv simply saying "I am available half-time".  Not enough here for an answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Note that, of course obviously, you have to state this when you first send in an email / cv.  It would be absurd to wait until a meeting to state this.  Good luck

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'd like to work one full-time job and one part-time job. I already have a full-time job. My full-time job is related to software engineering, while my part-time job would be more related to analytics & marketing.

Comment: @Eternal_Ether so you'd like to take a part time job in addition to your full-time job? Your question says in addition to your part time job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can I still apply for that job

Yes, no one will stop you from applying for any job in any way you want. Chances of landing the job are slim, but if you don't try you'll never know.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly apply. I'd strongly suggest adding your requirement for part time work into a cover letter though. It's no fun for a hiring manager if they get excited about a candidates CV and then learn that the candidate wants a part time role, if it's out of the question for the hiring company to accommodate it.

Yes, it'll mean more rejections, but at least when you get interest it's likely that they're open to the possibility and want to discuss further.